# Do quasitransitivity and completeness imply transitivity?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

Let $X$ be a set and let $R$ be a binary relation on $X$, i.e. $R \subseteq X^2$. For $(a,b) \in X^2$, let $a R b$ denote $(a,b) \in R$. Let $P$ be the antisymmetric subset of $R$. Define the properties:

1. Completeness (C): $a \lnot R b \implies b R a$
2. Quasitransitivity (Q): $a P b P c \implies a P c$
3. Transitivity (T): $a R b R c \implies a R c$

Here's my confusion: I can't tell if C+Q imply T.

**Argument 1.** *C+Q imply T*.

Suppose $a \lnot R b \lnot R c$. Completeness implies $c P b P a$; Quasitransitivity implies $c P a$. So $R$ is transitive since $c R b R a$ and $c R a$.

**Argument 2.** *C+Q do not imply T*.

Let $\succ_i$ and $\succ_j$ be complete strict transitive relations on $X$, and suppose they are as follows: $b \succ_i c \succ_i a$ and $c \succ_j a \succ_j b$.

Define $R$ as follows: for all $(a,b) \in X^2, a R b \iff a \succ_k b \text{ for some } k \in \{i,j\}$. Clearly, $R$ is complete. It is also quasitransitive,  since $a \lnot R b \lnot R c$ implies that $a \succ_k c$ for all $k$ due to transitivity of $\succ_k$, and thus $c \lnot R a$.  But it is not transitive: we have $a R b R c$ and yet $a \lnot R c$.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Have you written this correctly? What is the difference between $Q$ and $T$?

Comment: $Q$ is weaker than $T$ because it only requires transitivity of the antisymmetric relation $P$. To be clear: $a P b \iff (a R b \land b \lnot R a)$.

Comment: Can you explain why these aren't properties of binary relations? Both $P$ and $R$ are binary relations: only $P$ is defined to be antisymmetric.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you mean. It's just confusingly written. You say $R$ is quasitransitive if whenever $aRb$, and $bRc$, and $b\not R a$ and $c\not R b$, then $aRc$. The way it is written is looks like a property of $P$, not of $R$.

Comment: Yes, I assume $P \subseteq R$. And also: quasitransitive implies means that $a R b, b \lnot R a, b R c, c \lnot R b \implies a R c$  **and** $c \lnot R a$.

Comment: No, you **define** $P$; you don't assume something about $P$.

Comment: I guess I do not follow. I say in the first line that $P$ is the antisymmetric subset of $R$, so why is Q not a property of $R$?

Comment: "The way it is written it **looks** like a property of $P$, not of $R$". I'm talking about the need to parse the meaning rather than just read the sentence. You force the reader to jump back three sentences to understand the meaning. It is correct, I just found it confusing.

Comment: Your Argument 1 is not complete. To prove transitivity you need to prove that if $cRb$ and $bRa$, then $cRa$. You've shown this is the case if *both* $a\not Rb$ and $b\not R c$. What if $a Rb$ or $bRc$ hold? If you have a counterexample, just run your argument through it.

Comment: What do you mean by "the antisymmetric subset of $R$"? $R$ could have any number of antisymmetric subsets. (Aside: $a \lnot R b$ looks odd and $a \not R b$ and $a \not\mathrel{R} b$ don't typeset very nicely. I'd recommend $\lnot a \mathrel{R} b$  - that's \lnot a \mathrel{R} b.)

Comment: @RobArthan: Buried in comments...

Comment: I think you were thinking that $P$ would be trichotomic because $R$ is total; that isn't true in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not understand your "Argument 1". We assume that $R$ satisfies:

1. Completeness: rephrase, you have that for all $a,b$, either $aRb$ or $bRa$ (or possibly both).
2. Quasitransitivity: if $aRb$ and $bRc$, and in addition, $b\not Ra$ and $c\not Rb$, then $aRc$.

You define $P$ to be $P=\{(a,b)\in R\mid (b,a)\notin R\}$.  So $R$ is quasitransitive if and only if $P$ is transitive.

You want to show transitivity of $R$. So you are trying to show that $cRb$ and $bRa$ imply $cRa$ You show this to be the case when $a\not Rb$ and when $b\not Rc$.  Then it just follows from quasitransitivity; but what if one of them holds?  You should check what happens if $aRb$ and $b\not Rc$; if $a\not Rb$ and $b Rc$; and if $aRb$ and $bRc$. Why do you start by *assuming* that $a\not Rb$ and that $b\not R c$?

Take $X=\{a,b,c\}$, $R = \{(a,a), (b,b), (c,c), (a,b), (b,a), (b,c), (c,b), (a,c)\}$. This is total, but not transitive (since $(c,b)$ and $(b,a)$ are in $R$, but $(c,a)$ is not).

The relation $P$ you define is just $P=\{(a,c)\}$. This is transitive by vacuity, so $R$ is quasitransitive.

How does your Argument 1 fail here? We take $cRb$ and $bRa$. And then... your argument does not apply, because we do not have $a\not Rb$ and $b\not R c$. In fact, we have both $aRb$ and $bRc$.

Are you perhaps assuming that $P$ will be total when $R$ is total? As you can see from the example, that is not the case. In fact, $P$ is never total, since it is never reflexive. It is also not trichotomic in general.

Comment: Thank you! I was precisely assuming that $P$ would be total whenever $R$ is, clearly a mistake.

Comment: @raving-bandit: Well, it can't be total because $aRa$ always holds but $aPa$ never does. $P$ could be trichotomic (for all $a,b$, either $aPb$, or $bPa$, or $a=b$, and only one holds), though that will only be the case if $R$ is asymmetric.